# Momentjs utc shows correct date string, but wotks incorrectly

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I'm trying to compare two dates using momentjs. The first date is client date and it comes from browser in unix format already converted to UTC on client side. The second date is created on server side and it's behaviour is strange in my opinion. The code

```js
  const clientTimestamp = 1657709100000
  const currentDate = moment.utc()
  const clientDate = moment(clientTimestamp)
  
  console.log('currentDate', currentDate)
  console.log('clientDate', clientDate)
  console.log(currentDate.isBefore(clientDate))
```

returns the following output:

```
currentDate 2022-07-13T13:47:39Z
clientDate 2022-07-13T14:45:00+04:00
false
```

so, according to output, current date is before than clientDate, but `isBefore` function thinks othervise.

I can't find any other solution except of this hack:

```js
const currentDate = moment(moment().utc().format().replace('Z', ''))
```

Is there any method in momentjs to convert to utc in correct way?

Many thanks for any answer.

Comment: why do you think `2022-07-13T13:47:39Z` is before `2022-07-13T14:45:00+04:00`? If you convert `2022-07-13T14:45:00+04:00` to UTC you get `2022-07-13T10:45:00Z`. And `13:47` is obviously *not* before `10:45` , is it?

Comment: ah, derpirscher beat me to it

Comment: And the way moment js does convert your given timestamp to UTC *is the correct way*. What you are trying to do with your replacements is just plain wrong ...

Comment: @derpirscher thanks for answer. I want to make sure that client side date is not before than date created on server side immediately. So, how can I do it?

Comment: Generate a date on clientside, that is not in the future? I don't know when or how this clientside timestamp was created, but it seems, it depicts a timestamp in the future

Comment: Given the client timestamp is equivalent to an ECMAScript time value, you can just do `clientDate < Date.now()`.

Comment: Thanks everybody. The error was on the client side. @RobG your example directs me in a right way.